# Signed float to hexadecimal number

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, type-conversion

How to convert float to a specific format in hexadecimal:

1 bit for sign, 15 bit for the integer value, and the rest 16 bits for values after the decimal point.

Example output should be ffff587a for -0.6543861, fff31a35 for -12.897631, 006bde10 for 107.8674316, 003bd030 for 59.8132324

I have written a program that can do the unsigned conversion, I am stuck at the signed part. Could anyone guide me on how I can achieve this in a very compact way?

```
def convert(num):
    binary2 = ""
    Int = int(num)
    fract = num - Int
    binary = '{:16b}'.format(Int & 0b1111111111111111)

    for i in range (16):
        fract *= 2
        fract_bit = int(fract)
        if fract_bit == 1:
            fract -= fract_bit
            binary2 += '1'
        else:
            binary2 += '0'

    return int(binary + binary2, 2)

value = 107.867431640625
x = convert(value)

hex(x)
```

output: 0x6bde10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply the Q16.16 fixed-point format. To convert a floating-point number to this format, simply multiply it by 2<sup>16</sup> (in Python, `1<<16` or `65536`) and convert the product to an integer:

```py
y = int(x * (1<<16))
```

To show its 32-bit two’s complement representation, add 2<sup>32</sup> if it is negative and then convert it to hexadecimal:

```py
y = hex(y + (1<<32 if y < 0 else 0))
```

For example, the following prints “0xfff31a35”:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

x=-12.897631
y = int(x * (1<<16))
y = hex(y + (1<<32 if y < 0 else 0))
print(y)
```

This conversion truncates. If you want rounding, you can add .5 inside the `int` or you can add additional code for other types of rounding. You may also want to add code to handle overflows.